# Reading float value from WebBluetooth characteristic.readValue()

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I have a bluetooth module on a Raspberry pi which serves the cpu temperature of the board. I'm using `WebBluetooth` to make a web page that reads that info from the bluetooth module, the temperature is a float value "45.257" for example, the thing is that when I try to read the value, I don't know how to decodify that from the answer of the `readValue()` function, my code goes like this:

```
    async function onButtonClick() {
        let device = await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
            acceptAllDevices: true,
        });
        let server = await device.gatt.connect();
        console.log(server);
        let services = await server.getPrimaryServices();
        console.log(services);
        let characteristics = await services[0].getCharacteristics();
        let value = await characteristics[0].readValue();
        console.log(value);
    }
```

And the answer I'm getting is a `DataView` with the `ArrayBuffer`s

```
Int8Array(6) [52, 54, 46, 50, 53, 49]
Int16Array(3) [13876, 12846, 12597]
Uint8Array(6) [52, 54, 46, 50, 53, 49]
```

So I don't know how to retrieve a data like "45.257".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution using the `TextDecoder` class:

```
        const textDecoder = new TextDecoder('ascii');
        const value = textDecoder.decode(value.buffer);
        console.log(value);
```

Comment: This is a good solution but there's some context which is important to provide for both the question and solution. That is, that the data being generated by the Raspberry Pi is an ASCII string. This is somewhat easy to guess based on the Uint8Array data above because all the values are in the right range for being ASCII digits.

If the data were being sent as an actual float then you could use the getFloat32() or getFloat64() methods on the DataView object instead.